# How to choose SQL Vs nosql storage

Tags: mysql, sql, database, nosql

I have a project where I'm expecting large amount of live traffic and location information. The project hasn't started yet. I'm still in the architectural design phase. So there's no fear of migration or backward compatibility problems.

I have previous knowledge of mysql, and relational data bases, but this would be my first encounter with nosql.

My question is: should I choose a sql or nosql storage? I know there are lots of opinions about this issue, and I've been doing some reading, but I'm still not sure based on which  factors do I decide between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is how large your amount of traffic is going to be. NoSQL databases have the advantage that they scale very well because of their simpler data model (they can be easier distributed). But this also means that you have to give up a lot of stuff relational databases provide you. Those are first of all integrity mechanisms and a complex and convenient query language.

So i guess the first step is to make up your mind on your expected traffic and how much you need to scale. If a single database server will be able to handle the workload, you might want to go for a relational database.

The second aspect is the retrieval of your data. In relational databases you have SQL, which allows you to formulate very specific queries. On the other hand the relational model often forces you to distribute your data across multiple tables, even though they really belong together (Like an order + the ordered items). Thats one benefit of NoSQL databases like MongoDB where you would store things that belong together as a single document. Then the retrieval of this aggregate is also easy but if you want to do more complex queries you have to do it manually outside of the database.

So in the end you would use NoSQL mainly for simpler access patterns and if you want/need to scale. Relational DBMS have their advantage in the amount of functionality they give you. But for many tasks it is kind of unnatural to press your data into relations. Scaling is possible but more complicated.